# How do I switch views after signing up and logging in?

Tags: objective-c, authentication, parse-platform, uitextfield, viewcontroller

So the backend is working, I can successfully create accounts and login. Now I want them to transition to the home screen so how I do I set so if the sigup/login is successful it transitions? This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)signUp:(UIButton *)sender {


NSString *name      = _textUsername.text;
NSString *password  = _textPassword.text;
NSString *email     = [_textEmail.text lowercaseString];
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ([name length] == 0)     { [ProgressHUD showError:@"Name must be set."]; return; }
if ([password length] == 0) { [ProgressHUD showError:@"Password must be set."]; return; }
if ([email length] == 0)    { [ProgressHUD showError:@"Email must be set."]; return; }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ProgressHUD show:@"Please wait..." Interaction:NO];

PFUser *user = [PFUser user];
user.username = name;
user.password = password;
user.email = email;
user[PF_USER_EMAILCOPY] = email;
user[PF_USER_FULLNAME] = name;
user[PF_USER_FULLNAME_LOWER] = [name lowercaseString];
[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
 {
     if (error == nil)
     {
         ParsePushUserAssign();
         [ProgressHUD showSuccess:@"Succeed."];
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     }
     else [ProgressHUD showError:error.userInfo[@"error"]];
 }];
```

Also any idea why my text field doesn't automatically go to the next one? Pretty sure the code is right. Thanks.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField

  {
  if (textField == _textUsername)
 {

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [_textEmail becomeFirstResponder];
}

else if (textField == _textEmail)
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [_textPassword becomeFirstResponder];
}

else if (textField == _textPassword)
{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    [_textBirthday becomeFirstResponder];
}

else if (textField == _textBirthday)
{
 [self actionRegister];
}

return YES;
```

Comment: How about replace the signup: method with a one-liner that just does a dismissViewController.  You can probably cut parse out of this question.

Comment: @danh the view controller is already dismissed, I want to transition to another one after successfully signing up / logging in.

Comment: I see.  In that case, please post the code that detects the condition that there is no user and presents the signup /login.  (and remove the posted code, which has no bearing other than the dismiss).

Comment: The first screen has two buttons to 'Sign Up' and 'Login'. They just click the button that applies to them.

Answer (score 0):

The way I arrange my parse.com apps is to have the main VC, the one that does the app's usual business for a logged-in user, be the storyboard's starting VC.  It's first job in `viewDidAppear`, is to check that the PFUser currentUser exists (and is logged-in if your app requires it).  If it isn't, then and only then, present the login/signup VC.

When login/signup dismisses as you have it in the posted code, viewWillAppear in your main VC fires again and detects the ready-to-run condition.  It's action in that case is to carry on with initialization for a logged in user.

**EDIT** - For example, I have an app where the main VC is the starting VC in storyboard.  It has a segue with identifier == @"GetUser" drawn from it to my equivalent of your signup/login VC.

Here's the (slightly simplified) `viewDidAppear` from my main VC.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // I require only a non-nil currentUser to run the app.  Your check
    // might be more elaborate...
    PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
    if (user) {
        // put up a "busy" UI.  In my app, it's just a view with UIActivityIndicator
        // update the user so we know its current
        [user fetchInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
            // remove the "busy" UI
            [self startTheApp];
        }];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GetUser" sender:self];
    }
}

-(void)startTheApp {
    // fetch data from parse.com and reload the table view that's the 
    // centerpiece of the UI for this VC.
}
```

The nice behavior here is when the login/signup succeeds, the currentUser is non-nil, so when the login/signup VC is dismissed, `viewDidAppear` as shown above is fired again because the main VC underneath is being revealed again.  And on that second time through, the currentUser passes the starting condition and we go to `startTheApp`.

Comment: sure.  see edit.  the interesting part of your question relates mostly to code in the present-ING view controller, and hardly at all to the present-ED view controller that you have in the question.

Comment: Thanks, got no errors but, nothing seems to happen. This is in the main view controller (what the user would see logged in) - http://i.imgur.com/1gUXxsQ.png

Comment: The startTheApp code shouldn't signup a user.  It should do whatever the main vc needs to do to start running, presuming a good user.  The "GetUser" segue should present your login/signup vc.